# Keep else, catch, on same line as closing bracket in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I've managed to get Visual Studio to keep the opening bracket on the same line like this (the settings for this are under `Formatting -> New Lines`; the settings I am looking for, if they exist, are not in this area of options):

```
void foo() {
  bar();
}
```

but I can't figure out how to keep **else** and **catch** blocks on the same line as the ending bracket of the previous statement.

To clarify, this is what Visual Studio auto-formats to:

```
if (foo) {
  return 1;
}
else {
  return 2;
}
```

and this is what I want:

```
if (foo) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 2;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you have tried. There's a set of options specifically for this under `Formatting -> New Lines`. Have you tried them and found them not to work as advertised?

Comment: @bogdan the only options under that setting are for the location of opening braces. I tried to convey this with my initial statement about finding the options for the opening bracket which are located in `Formatting -> New Lines`. I'll edit and make this explicit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to `Tool`->`Option` then `General`->`Text editor`->`C++` -> `Formatting` -> `New lines`.

Choose the following settings:

- Position of opening brace for control block: radio button for *same line*
- Position of keyword:  uncheck the *else on new line*.

The preview for this last setting will display

```
if (a < b)
{
} else
{
}
```

but this doesn't take into account the first option.

If you type an if/else statement, select the region, and ask the editor to reformat.  The statement will appear as:

```
if (test) {
} else {
}
```

I could try this successfully on Visual Studio 2015.  I tested it with a foreign language, so the english wording of above mentioned options might be slightly different, but close enough for being found.

Comment: Wow I must just be blind. I read through those options like ten times and somehow missed those. Thank you very much

Comment: I imported this setting from 2013 and in general it works, means if I let reformat the whole document everything is fine. But if I type »} else {« and then enter, 2013 put the else in a new line and then the opening curly brace in a new line. But 2015 only put the opening brace in a new line and leaves the »else« in the same line as the closing brace. So the setting is correct. Has anyone a clue, why it don't work. Does everyone has this problem or only me?